# How can I pass a prop to onBlur() and use a predefined function at the same time (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Text Input component that change its background color using onBlur and onFocus events. What I want to do is to pass another function to onBlur using props, so the component would perform both actions.

This is my component:

```
const Input: React.FC<TextInputProps> = (props) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("#f2f2f2");

    return (
        <TextInput
            onFocus={() => setColor('#f9ffc4')}
            onBlur={() => setColor('#f2f2f2')} // I would like to use props.onBlur here in addition to setColor()
            onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
            style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
            value={props.value}
        >
        </TextInput>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

And this is how I use it:

```
return (
    <Input
        onChangeText={ handleChange('cpf') }
        value={values.cpf}
        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('cpf')} //I want to call it along with the method declared in the component
    />
    {touched.cpf && errors.cpf &&
        <Text style={{ color: 'red', width: '100%', textAlign: 'right' }}>{errors.cpf} </Text>
    }
)
```

I know that I could use setColor() here, but I have lots of other inputs and if I did that, I would have to create an useState const for each one of them, and that's not what I want.

If someone could help me here I would really appreciate it, and if something is not clear in my question, just ask me and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onBlur={() => {
  setColor('#f2f2f2');
  props.onBlur();
}}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I have already tried this way, but like this the only thing that happens is setColor(), the other methods won't be passed through props, this is what confuses me.

Comment: There is a difference between your edit and this answer, look closely

Comment: **props.onBlur();** not **props.onBlur**

Comment: @ArifArifi @konstantin sorry for my lack of attention, **props.onBlur()** gives me this error on vscode: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. An argument for 'e' was not provided.` so i tought it would not work, but it does. Can I keep it like this with this error showing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this to get rid of that error you were bothered about:

```
const Input: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({onBlur, onChangeText, value}) => { destructured for code readability
    const [color, setColor] = useState("#f2f2f2");

    const handleBlur = (event) => {
        setColor('#f2f2f2');
        onBlur(event); // This is passed as a prop with its event which is needed to rid that undefined TypeError.
    }

    return (
        <TextInput
            onFocus={() => setColor('#f9ffc4')}
            onBlur={handleBlur} // The function here has an event that you will need to pass.
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
            value={value}
        >
        </TextInput>
    )
}

export default Input;
```